# Trying to create a GET request to pubgtracker

Tags: api, http, get, request, tracker

I am trying to practice my developing and wanna build my own desktop application using: https://pubgtracker.com/site-api

Before I even start the project I want to make sure that I manage to receive information from the PUBG api. Therefore I opened https://www.hurl.it/
and I try to enter the following:

GET request, and in the destination https://api.pubgtracker.com/v2/profile/pc/{pubg-nickname} (for example lucifini1 currently ranked #1)

In addition they request the API key as a header so I did the following:
 + ADD HEADER,
 In the name field added TRN-Api-Key
and in the value I added my key.

When I launch request i get an: internal server error.

How can I debug it and know what I am missing?
Am I doing it correctly?

Thanks

Comment: have you solve this issue? If so please let us know

Comment: Yeah, Apparently all I needed to do is to create my own GET request through the C#, somehow through the website it didn't work.
dont forget to add the TRN-Api-Key as a header.
If you want I will post the code

Comment: I am trying to use php to get the data. But not working .

Comment: Ahhh sorry mate, dont got knowledge in PHP...